# Calculate future date based on date field

Tags: sql, sql-server

How I can calculate a date in the future based on the date of a field?

For example, I have a field in my dataset called `SPS_START_DATE` and I need to create a second field which is 20 weeks on from this date. What SQL would be required to calculate the date 20 weeks into the future?

Comment: What's wrong with [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Try `select DATEADD(week, 20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` and see what you get from that. Use that on your SPS_START_DATE

Comment: Considering that W3School's [SQL Server DATEADD() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp) article is the very first result when you search [How to add 20 weeks to a date sql server](https://www.google.com/search?&q=How+to+add+20+weeks+to+a+date+sql+server); I can only agree, @Jodrell .

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, use [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT
         DATEADD(week, 20, [SPS_START_DATE])
    FROM
         [My DataSet];
```

Answer (score 0):

[DATEADD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is perfect for this.

For example:

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS DateTime, --Get the date/time from today
CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DateOnly, --Cast date/time value as date only
DATEADD(wk, 20, GETDATE()) AS TwentyWeeksDateTime, --Get the date/time of 20 weeks from now
CAST(DATEADD(wk, 20, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS TwentyWeeksDate --Cast date/time value as date only
```